# Dataset in Spark 1.6

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I am evaluating to replace existing RDD code to Dataset. For one of my usecases, I am unable to map a Dataset to another case class.

Here is what I am trying to do...

```
case class MyMap(map: Map[String, String])

case class V1(a: String, b: String){
  def toMyMap: MyMap = {
    MyMap(Map(a->b))
  }

  def toStr: String = {
    a
  }
}

object MyApp extends App {
//Get handle to sqlContext and other useful stuff here.
val df1 = sqlContext.createDataset(Seq(V1("2015-05-01", "data1"), V1("2015-05-01", "data2"))).toDF()
df1.as[V1].map(_.toMyMap).show() //Errors out. Added the exception below.
df1.as[V1].map(_.toStr).show() //Works fine.
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

With the following exception:

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job
>   aborted due to stage failure: Task not serializable:
>   java.io.NotSerializableException:
>   scala.reflect.runtime.SynchronizedSymbols$SynchronizedSymbol$$anon$1
>   Serialization stack:
>     - object not serializable (class: scala.reflect.runtime.SynchronizedSymbols$SynchronizedSymbol$$anon$1,
>   value: package lang)
>     - field (class: scala.reflect.internal.Types$ThisType, name: sym, type: class scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol)
>     - object (class scala.reflect.internal.Types$UniqueThisType, java.lang.type)
>     - field (class: scala.reflect.internal.Types$TypeRef, name: pre, type: class scala.reflect.internal.Types$Type)
>     - object (class scala.reflect.internal.Types$ClassNoArgsTypeRef, String)
>     - field (class: scala.reflect.internal.Types$TypeRef, name: normalized, type: class scala.reflect.internal.Types$Type)
>     - object (class scala.reflect.internal.Types$AliasNoArgsTypeRef, String)
>     - field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$6, name:
>   keyType$1, type: class scala.reflect.api.Types$TypeApi)
>     - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$6, )
>     - field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.MapObjects, name: function, type: interface scala.Function1)
>     - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.MapObjects, mapobjects(,invoke(upcast('map,MapType(StringType,StringType,true),-
>   field (class: "scala.collection.immutable.Map", name: "map"),- root
>   class:
>   "collector.MyMap"),keyArray,ArrayType(StringType,true)),StringType))
>     - field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Invoke, name: targetObject, type: class
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Expression)
>     - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Invoke, invoke(mapobjects(,invoke(upcast('map,MapType(StringType,StringType,true),-
>   field (class: "scala.collection.immutable.Map", name: "map"),- root
>   class:
>   "collector.MyMap"),keyArray,ArrayType(StringType,true)),StringType),array,ObjectType(class
>   [Ljava.lang.Object;)))
>     - writeObject data (class: scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy)
>     - object (class scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy, scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy@7e78c3cf)
>     - writeReplace data (class: scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy)
>     - object (class scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon, List(invoke(mapobjects(,invoke(upcast('map,MapType(StringType,StringType,true),-
>   field (class: "scala.collection.immutable.Map", name: "map"),- root
>   class:
>   "collector.MyMap"),keyArray,ArrayType(StringType,true)),StringType),array,ObjectType(class
>   [Ljava.lang.Object;)),
>   invoke(mapobjects(,invoke(upcast('map,MapType(StringType,StringType,true),-
>   field (class: "scala.collection.immutable.Map", name: "map"),- root
>   class:
>   "collector.MyMap"),valueArray,ArrayType(StringType,true)),StringType),array,ObjectType(class
>   [Ljava.lang.Object;))))
>     - field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.StaticInvoke, name:
>   arguments, type: interface scala.collection.Seq)
>     - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.StaticInvoke,
>   staticinvoke(class
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.ArrayBasedMapData$,ObjectType(interface
>   scala.collection.Map),toScalaMap,invoke(mapobjects(,invoke(upcast('map,MapType(StringType,StringType,true),-
>   field (class: "scala.collection.immutable.Map", name: "map"),- root
>   class:
>   "collector.MyMap"),keyArray,ArrayType(StringType,true)),StringType),array,ObjectType(class
>   [Ljava.lang.Object;)),invoke(mapobjects(,invoke(upcast('map,MapType(StringType,StringType,true),-
>   field (class: "scala.collection.immutable.Map", name: "map"),- root
>   class:
>   "collector.MyMap"),valueArray,ArrayType(StringType,true)),StringType),array,ObjectType(class
>   [Ljava.lang.Object;)),true))
>     - writeObject data (class: scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy)
>     - object (class scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy, scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy@377795c5)
>     - writeReplace data (class: scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy)
>     - object (class scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon, List(staticinvoke(class
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.ArrayBasedMapData$,ObjectType(interface
>   scala.collection.Map),toScalaMap,invoke(mapobjects(,invoke(upcast('map,MapType(StringType,StringType,true),-
>   field (class: "scala.collection.immutable.Map", name: "map"),- root
>   class:
>   "collector.MyMap"),keyArray,ArrayType(StringType,true)),StringType),array,ObjectType(class
>   [Ljava.lang.Object;)),invoke(mapobjects(,invoke(upcast('map,MapType(StringType,StringType,true),-
>   field (class: "scala.collection.immutable.Map", name: "map"),- root
>   class:
>   "collector.MyMap"),valueArray,ArrayType(StringType,true)),StringType),array,ObjectType(class
>   [Ljava.lang.Object;)),true)))
>     - field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.NewInstance, name:
>   arguments, type: interface scala.collection.Seq)
>     - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.NewInstance,
>   newinstance(class collector.MyMap,staticinvoke(class
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.ArrayBasedMapData$,ObjectType(interface
>   scala.collection.Map),toScalaMap,invoke(mapobjects(,invoke(upcast('map,MapType(StringType,StringType,true),-
>   field (class: "scala.collection.immutable.Map", name: "map"),- root
>   class:
>   "collector.MyMap"),keyArray,ArrayType(StringType,true)),StringType),array,ObjectType(class
>   [Ljava.lang.Object;)),invoke(mapobjects(,invoke(upcast('map,MapType(StringType,StringType,true),-
>   field (class: "scala.collection.immutable.Map", name: "map"),- root
>   class:
>   "collector.MyMap"),valueArray,ArrayType(StringType,true)),StringType),array,ObjectType(class
>   [Ljava.lang.Object;)),true),false,ObjectType(class
>   collector.MyMap),None))
>     - field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder, name:
>   fromRowExpression, type: class
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Expression)
>     - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder,
>   class[map#ExprId(9,255a02aa-f2fa-482d-8cd1-63e2d4d08b30):
>   map])
>     - field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.MapPartitions, name: uEncoder, type: class
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder)
>     - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.execution.MapPartitions, !MapPartitions , class[a[0]: string, b[0]: string],
>   class[map#ExprId(9,255a02aa-f2fa-482d-8cd1-63e2d4d08b30):
>   map], [map#13]
>   +- LocalTableScan [a#2,b#3], [[0,180000000a,2800000005,2d35302d35313032,3130,3161746164],[0,180000000a,2800000005,2d35302d35313032,3130,3261746164]]
>   )
>     - field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.MapPartitions$$anonfun$8, name: $outer,
>   type: class org.apache.spark.sql.execution.MapPartitions)
>     - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.execution.MapPartitions$$anonfun$8, )
>     - field (class: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1, name: f$22,
>   type: interface scala.Function1)
>     - object (class org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1,
>   )
>     - field (class: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$21,
>   name: $outer, type: class
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1)
>     - object (class org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$21,
>   )
>     - field (class: org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD, name: f, type: interface scala.Function3)
>     - object (class org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD, MapPartitionsRDD[1] at show at CollectorSparkTest.scala:50)
>     - field (class: org.apache.spark.NarrowDependency, name: *rdd, type: class org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD)
>     - object (class org.apache.spark.OneToOneDependency, org.apache.spark.OneToOneDependency@110f15b7)
>     - writeObject data (class: scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy)
>     - object (class scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy, scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy@6bb23696)
>     - writeReplace data (class: scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy)
>     - object (class scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon, List(org.apache.spark.OneToOneDependency@110f15b7))
>     - field (class: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD, name: org$apache$spark$rdd$RDD$$dependencies*, type: interface
>   scala.collection.Seq)
>     - object (class org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD, MapPartitionsRDD[2] at show at CollectorSparkTest.scala:50)
>     - field (class: scala.Tuple2, name: _1, type: class java.lang.Object)
>     - object (class scala.Tuple2, (MapPartitionsRDD[2] at show at CollectorSparkTest.scala:50,))     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1431)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1419)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
>     at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
>     at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.submitMissingTasks(DAGScheduler.scala:1010)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$submitStage(DAGScheduler.scala:921)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleJobSubmitted(DAGScheduler.scala:861)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1607)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1588)
>     at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:620)
>     at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1832)    at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1845)     at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1858)     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:212)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Limit.executeCollect(basicOperators.scala:165)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollectPublic(SparkPlan.scala:174)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$execute$1$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1538)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$execute$1$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1538)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:56)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.withNewExecutionId(DataFrame.scala:2125)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$execute$1(DataFrame.scala:1537)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$collect(DataFrame.scala:1544)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$head$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1414)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$head$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1413)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.withCallback(DataFrame.scala:2138)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.head(DataFrame.scala:1413)    at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.take(DataFrame.scala:1495)     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.showString(DataFrame.scala:171)    at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.show(DataFrame.scala:394)  at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:228)  at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:192)  at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:200)

Answer (score 2):

I think you might actually be hitting [SPARK-12696](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-12696), which is fixed in spark/master.  I'm hoping to release 1.6.1 in the near future, which should include this patch.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the scala Map class is not serializable, so the Dataset API cannot automatically generate an appropriate encoder. I would suggest converting the map into a string and then later parse the string and convert back to a map (assuming you are storing strings in the map).

The Dataset API might not be the best choice either. I wrote [this article](http://www.agildata.com/apache-spark-rdd-vs-dataframe-vs-dataset/), which might be of interest.